# How can an azure pipeline template reference a file living in same template repo?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an azure pipeline template repo which contains a bash script which I would like to source in each Bash@3 step of that same template repo

all files mentioned here live in the same pipeline template repo and not in the calling client pipeline

here is a typical bash step in the template

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'some cool bash step'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |

      echo
      echo "wussup Willis?"
      echo
      source ./shared_functions.sh # lives in same template repo as this bash step
```

challenge here is if above is a pipeline template step the attempt to source a file from same template repo fails with file not found ... ability to reference a file seems to only work if the bash step is in a client pipeline and the file its referring to also lives in same client pipeline repo

Any suggestions on how to refer to a file living in same repo as the pipeline template repo ?

Comment: Where is the file located? Is the repo being checked out/the artifact being downloaded in  the pipelines that consume your template? Are you getting a specific error? Share both your template and the pipeline referencing the template.

Comment: @DanielMann I updated my question ... all files live in same template repo

Comment: You didn't provide the additional information I requested. Share the complete YAML files and any error messages you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You need to checkout the repository containing the templates as well

Comment: Is it possible to do that checkout in the template yaml file that is called? In other words, does a `checkout: self` within the template checkout the template repo or the calling repo (again)?

Comment: I can answer my own question. The "self" refers to the calling repo unfortunately. Is there a way to "checkout" the "template repo" instead of "self"?